# Convert VARCHAR to BINARY(16)

Tags: c#, sql-server, binary

I'm trying to decode a SQL Server column that contains binary data as `varchar` datatype.

I've seen in some other topics and places how to convert it to binary, but their solutions don't work for me unfortunately.

I have a table name called `TABLE_TEST` that have 1 column called `SomeData` as `varchar(400)` data type.

If I click to edit the table, I see that there is some data there, but if I run a simple query:

```
SELECT SomeData 
FROM TABLE_TEST
```

The data won't show as it's binary data.

So reading in some other places, I go ahead and try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), SomeData, 1)  
FROM TABLE_TEST
```

I also tried with style 2 and it shows:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.

I know that this data is completely fine, as when I read it in c# application, I simply do this:

```
byte[] someDataBuffer = new byte[400];
MemoryStream someDataStream = new MemoryStream(someDataBuffer);
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(someDataStream);
Int32 data1 = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
Int16 data2 = binaryReader.ReadInt16();
Int16 data3 = binaryReader.ReadInt16();
```

Is there a way to get the same results or query just on SQL side?
I mean a query where it converts the varchar column to binary and then I can read that data structure same way in SQL.

EDIT1:
Note that the binary column size is 400, so basically varchar(400) and the way i read everyting is in a for loop 50 times. Because every loop I read an Int32 and then Int16 and Int16. So that means 8 bytes in total * 50 times = 400(the size of the column).

I though of running it something like this:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0;
WHILE @i < 50
BEGIN
    -- Read Int32
    -- Read Int16
    -- Read Int16
    SET @i = @i + 1;    
END
```

But how would i decode every time part of the data there?

EDIT2: 
It looks like @DavidDubois answer goes to the right direction. But I'm still not sure why it won't work when I try to read that data in SQL, it could be some encoding problem. I added a picture to show the way it looks like so it gives the idea:
[image]
When I try to select this data or copy this data, it won't copy anything.
That's why It makes me think that the encoding is set to something special. How do i check this?
The Collation of that database and column is set to: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: Can you post an example of such varchar string?

Comment: @Evk I update the question. It doesn't let me copy it, because it contains some weird characters as It's binary data. When i mark the column to copy, it doesn't copy anything.

Comment: Well it's harder to help then. I thought it's something like hex or base64 string, but it seems to be real string in some encoding. And why you are doing that? Storing binary in varchar is not a good idea.

Comment: @Evk It's an old database that an old application depend on. That why I have to stick to that bad database design. Would a Screenshot help of the way the data looks like in that column?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
-- A varchar(400) value actually contains binary data
-- That data consists of 50 triplets.
-- Each triplet consists of a 32-bit integer, and two 16-bit integers
-- How does one pull out these values from the original data?

-- Note that data is stored in little-endian format, while SQL Server uses BIG-endian, 
-- so we need to use REVERSE

-- Declare variables to hold the triplet values
-- @i32 holds a 32-bit integer (int), while @j16 and @k16 holds 16-bit integers (smallint)
declare @i32 int
declare @j16 smallint
declare @k16 smallint

-- @C will hold the varchar(400) data
-- @B will be used to hold that same data in a binary representation
declare @C varchar(400)
declare @B varbinary(400)

-- As a test, let's first build such a string

-- The binary value starts empty
set @B = 0x

-- Loop 50 times
declare @i int
set @i=1
while @i<=50 
begin
  -- I've arbitrarily chosen values to store
  set @i32 = 1000000000-7777777 * @i
  set @j16 = @i32 % 11111
  set @k16 = @i32 % 9999

  print    'I=' + cast ( @i32 as varchar(10)) 
        + ' J=' + cast ( @j16 as varchar(10))
        + ' K=' + cast ( @k16 as varchar(10))

  -- Convert each of the three values to varbinary, and append them to the complete binary value

  set @B = @B + cast ( Reverse ( cast ( @i32 as varbinary(4))) as varbinary(4))
              + cast ( Reverse ( cast ( @j16 as varbinary(2))) as varbinary(2))
              + cast ( Reverse ( cast ( @k16 as varbinary(2))) as varbinary(2))

  set @i=@i+1
end

-- This is what it looks like in binary
select @B as [In Binary]

-- Convert that binary value to characters
set @C = cast ( @B as varchar(400))

-- Let's look at those characters.  They won't make much sense
select @C as [As Characters]

-- Now let's take that example, and reverse the process

-- Convert the character value back to binary

set @B = cast ( @C as varbinary(400))

--set @B = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080C69706EB280100000000000000000080C69706A22601000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

-- Loop 50 times

set @i=1
while @i<50 
begin
  -- Pull out the appropriate bytes for each value, and convert those values back to integers

  set @i32 = cast( cast(Reverse(substring( @B, @i*8-7, 4 ))as varbinary(4)) as int      )

  set @j16 = cast( cast(Reverse(substring( @B, @i*8-3, 2 ))as varbinary(2)) as smallint )

  set @k16 = cast( cast(Reverse(substring( @B, @i*8-1, 2 ))as varbinary(2)) as smallint )

  -- Let's take a look
  select @i as [Idx], @i32 as [I], @j16 as [J], @k16 as [K]

  set @i=@i+1
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed example! I'm still not sure why it won't work for me. Maybe different encoding? is there a way to check this? for a test, I changed where you cast @B to varchar again and wrote it as so:
set @C = (SELECT TOP 1 SomeData FROM TABLE_TEST) and it didn't work unfortunately. Am i missing something?

Comment: Added picture of the way the encoding looks like.

Comment: How about this:    We need to see the BINARY representation of your data.   So please run this query:  select top 1 cast (SomeData as varbinary(400)) from Table_Test.       And then also tell us what numbers you expect to see when you read that data.

Comment: or, add   "select @B"     after   "set @B = cast ( @C as varbinary(400))"

Comment: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080C69706EB280100000000000000000080C69706A22601000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: The numbers of the Int32 should be 9 digits from 100,000,000 to 999,999,999. Then the 2 other Int16 doesn't have restriction. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: SQL Server is treating the values as BIG-endian, while they appear to be stored LITTLE-endian.   The byte order needs to be swapped.

Comment: This is awesome! Seriously you're genius! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
DECLARE @TestString VARCHAR(100) = 'Test' ;

SELECT  @TestString AS [Raw],
        CONVERT(VARBINARY(100), @TestString) AS BinaryFromString,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CONVERT(VARBINARY(100), @TestString)) AS StringFromBinary ;
```

You can test it here: http://rextester.com/OZRW13368

Comment: Thank you, that looks interesting, but I read here values instead of strings. I update the question so it's more clear what I'm referring to.

Comment: You can convert between int and varchar and keep it simple.